# Flyway migration using JNDI

Tags: jndi, flyway

I am doing migration using flyway. I have used flyway configuration file which can be changed based on environment (dev/test/prod). But for application I am using JNDI lookup for database connectivity in tomcat's server.xml file.

But the problem is I want to make it common for both flyway and application so that we don't make mistakes to change some configuration at one file and forget in another one.

Also I am looking for a solution which can be applied with any Java or PHP application irrespective of framework used(e.g. spring)
Any help???

Comment: In your Spring application, you can use the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. It supports JNDI lookup. I wrote a blog post about this topic (see http://wp.me/p1RmNp-6F)